# Luanching an exe/bat file when opening a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, automation, exe

I've written up a script to do some background loading of a very large multi-project solution folder.
And I've created external tools to launch these scripts manually.

But I need to find a way to automatically launch said scripts with arguments on the launch of this solution. Before everything else loads.

I've tried looking at dozens of answers but they mostly explain just how to set up an external tool and hook it to a keybind, but I need automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Open a file from the solution directory on opening a solution](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnSolutionOpened) extension for Visual Commander and replace opening a file with launching it.